# Image with Multiple Clickable Areas

Tags: wpf, image, click

I have an image that I want various parts of to be clickable. I found a comment in the question below mentioning this was possible with Expression Designer. I haven't been able to find a guide on how to do this. I understand that I have to export the image from Designer to Visual Studio. Is there a better way of achieving this or how do I go about creating the xaml for these clickable sections?

[best way for clickable image map in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991076/best-way-for-clickable-image-map-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd use the second answer to that question i.e. do something like this:

```
<Canvas>
    <Image Source="background.png"/>
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="82" Canvas.Top="88" Width="442" Height="216" Fill="Transparent" Cursor="Hand" MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown_1"/>
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="305" Canvas.Top="309" Width="100" Height="50" Fill="Transparent" Cursor="Hand" MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown_2"/>
</Canvas>
```

Then you can drag and resize the shapes in DevStudio using it's XAML editor's design mode.

Comment: At home I usually use Visual Studio Express 2012, but any version since 2008 or so should work...I think...

Comment: Oh right there in VS? Didn't realise you could pull around the Ellipse from in there. Will try that!