# On click event to part of an image WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got an iPhone image that I'd like to place a click event on the home button.

How can I accomplish this with WPF? I've tried placing a button on the image but I didn't get the desired result.

> What type of control do you use for your image?

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Skin/full.png" Stretch="Fill">
    </ImageBrush>
</Window.Background>
```

Comment: What type of control do you use for your image?

Comment: @FiN:

<Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Skin/full.png" Stretch="Fill"></ImageBrush>
    </Window.Background>

Comment: WPF has anything to do with iPhone?

Comment: @LeiYang He is using image of iPhone.

 Could you use another type of container?  Grid,Canvas?

Comment: I mean, why do you talk about images of iPhone, instead image of Android, or image of a man and click his head, etc?

Comment: @LeiYang It doesn't matter. He just specified his case, which might have added confusion to the question - which has now been cleared. He just wants a clickable image.

Comment: **clickable image** is much more better. @KamilSolecki but I'm afraid the OP want to do some remoting or hacking, do you believe?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a button and put the image inside it.
 <Button Command="{Binding ButtonClickedCommand}">
    <Image Source="Images/Skin/full.png" />
</Button>
Or you can just use the MouseDown event when using an <Image>.

Comment: @FiN: I can use any other control, I just have to ensure that only a certain part of the image is clickable.

Comment: @LeiYang No, I don't think so, judging from what he has said so far.
I'm still fairly sure it's just a clickable image :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the image in a suitable panel like `Canvas` or `Grid` and use invisible buttons as overlay.

In resources:

```
<Style x:Key="InvisibleButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<Grid Width="150" Height="150">
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Skin/full.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <Button x:Name="TopLeft" Margin="0,0,100,100" Click="TopLeft_Click" Style="{StaticResource InvisibleButtonStyle}"/>
    <Button x:Name="TopRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="TopRight_Click" Margin="0,0,0,100" Width="100" Style="{StaticResource InvisibleButtonStyle}"/>
    <Button x:Name="BottomLeft" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="BottomLeft_Click" Margin="0,0,100,0" Height="100" Style="{StaticResource InvisibleButtonStyle}"/>
    <Button x:Name="BottomRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="BottomRight_Click" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="100" Height="100" Style="{StaticResource InvisibleButtonStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Note I added a red border to the transparent button in order to highlight the clickable areas, in reality it would only be transparent background.

Comment: Now I have the issue that the content of my usercontrol is now getting hidden because of the canvas on the MainWindow.

Do you have any suggestions to around this?

Comment: @John since you don't provide your composition (window and usercontrol) in the question, I most certainly don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a part of image to be clickable, I would suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20319031/3128927) solution.

C/P from link...

```
<Canvas>
    <Image Source="background.png"/>
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="82" Canvas.Top="88" Width="442" Height="216" Fill="Transparent" Cursor="Hand" MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown_1"/>
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="305" Canvas.Top="309" Width="100" Height="50" Fill="Transparent" Cursor="Hand" MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown_2"/>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this by doing the following:

```
<Canvas Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,394,0,0" Width="220">
            <Button Content="" Canvas.Left="102" Canvas.Top="6" Background="Transparent" Width="16" BorderBrush="Transparent" Cursor="Hand" >
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
</Canvas>
```

Just have to set your margins and Canvas left and top positions to overlay the clickable area.